# Playing Guitar Tabs on Piano

Tags: guitar, piano, digital-piano

I was wondering if anyone could possibly explain how I could somehow translate a guitar tab into notes on piano. Is there some sort of algorithm I can apply? 
 ex:

```
E|--------------------------------------------------------------9/12--|

B|---------------------7h9--12--12--12--10--10\9--9--9\7--7--7--------|

G|--------------6h8/9-------------------------------------------------|  

D|--6h7--6h7/9--------------------------------------------------------|

A|--------------------------------------------------------------------|

E|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: This approach embraces all of the worst aspects on TAB, while providing none of the benefits! I would learn standard music notation, or just play by ear.

Comment: If you are asking for an algorithm to do this, you might try different SE sites, for which your question would be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple: the strings (EADGBE) each correspond to a certain (white) key of the piano keyboard. For example, the E is the white key at the end of a group of two black keys (see the blue circle below). *Which* E key (i.e. which octave) can usually be heard, but on most pianos the second E from the bottom corresponds to the lowest E string of a guitar.

Then, the number in the tab is just the number of half-tones (white *and* black keys) you need to go up. E.g. the first note in your tab is a 6 on the D string. If you go up 6 keys from D, you end up on the black G#/Ab key. See the red marks below.

[image]